# netstat: grep lines related to a specific process

Tags: windows, powershell, netstat

I know that, in Windows, you could do the following to see what processes are attached to a port:

```
netstat -a -b
```

However, how would you limit the display to ports attached to a specific process? I looked at *findstr* but that doesn't help because the process' executable is not mentioned on the same line as the port information:

```
PS C:\Users\nimmylebby> netstat -a -b
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49154             NIMMY-LAPTOP:0         LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49155             NIMMY-LAPTOP:0         LISTENING
 [services.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49156             NIMMY-LAPTOP:0         LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
```

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [Sysinternals TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437), which includes a command line version that lets you filter on a process name:

> Using Tcpvcon
>
> Tcpvcon usage is similar to that of
>   the built-in Windows netstat utility:
>
> Usage: tcpvcon [-a] [-c] [-n] [process
>   name or PID]
>
> -a    Show all endpoints (default is to show established TCP connections).
>   -c    Print output as CSV.
>   -n    Don't resolve addresses..

Comment: The page for TCPView apparently moved; it appears to be available under http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437 now.